# How to recreate the iOS 7 Weather App view controller transition

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, transition

I've been trying to recreate the iOS 7 Weather App's view controller transition.  It looks like they might be doing a UICollectionView with cells arranged like a table view, and when it transitions it switches to a different collection view with full screen cells and horizontal scrolling.  The problem is recreating the transition between the two.

The natural transition between the two has all the cells growing and moving into place, where as the Weather app has one cell that grows and all other cells just slide out of the way.

Any thoughts on how this transition be recreated?

Comment: It looks to me like it's just a UITableView that changes the contents and size of the selected cell.  It's also possible that it's essentially a modal presentation with a custom animation.

Comment: @David That's what it looks like during the animation, but it's behavior in full screen mode makes me think its some kind of view controller transition.

Answer (score 0):

It is done using the new iOS 7 Transitioning API's

Check out the [`UICollectionViewTransitionLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewTransitionLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference for handling transitions between collection view layouts and [this helpful blog post](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html) about custom transitions in general.

It might also be worth downloading [this sample project](https://github.com/timarnold/UICollectionView-Transition-Demo) as it also transitions between two collection view layouts.

Also, have a look at the **Custom Transitions Using View Controllers** 2013 WWDC session video over in the [developer centre](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/).

Comment: I don't doubt that it's some sort of view controller transition, but it's definitely not a collection view transition.  They give very limited control over the animation, and definitely not enough to reproduce the effect I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you share you could if you have done it? That would be really cool :)

Comment: @drale2k I haven't done it myself so cannot do that i'm afraid. InkGolem, Are you sure about that? From what I have seen and experienced, the API allows you to do a lot of things. Essentially, all you are doing is transitioning from a tableView based layout (the vertical list of cells) to a paged based layout (the full screen horizontal scrolling of cells). What part don't you think is achievable?

Answer (score -2):

You may want to check this link.  https://github.com/BTLibrary/BTGlassScrollView

He did a simple solution.

> The view is a subclass of a UIView. It contains 2 scrollViews,
>   background and foreground. backgroundScrollView consists of 2
>   imageviews, normal and blurred. The alpha of the blurred one changes
>   as the background scrolls. And the background scrolls as the
>   foreground scrolls (at a different rate). The foregroundScrollView
>   consists of maskLayers (gradient) and the foregroundView (which is
>   whatever you want it to be). Between foreground and background, 2
>   shadowsLayer is added on the top and bottom to give a better
>   readability.

I am using this on my app after modifying a bit and works fine